# Azure Iot Rest API Message from cloud to device

Tags: azure, iot

Get : `https://myiot.azure-devices.net/devices/mydevice/messages/devicebound?api-version=2016-02-03`

Authorization: SAS key

i am getting 204 No content response from above api while receiving message using postman request maker from cloud to device.When i send messages from device to cloud it is appearing in my iot hub but giving error 204 while receiving messages from cloud.

Comment: You really didn't provide much to work with. Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: Have you send Cloud-To-Device message before you call this GET api? How did you do that?

Comment: no ,i just send device to cloud message ,then try to get the message from above api.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you haven't sent Cloud-To-Device messages and you get No content response(error code:204) from calling the GET api(`https://myiot.azure-devices.net/devices/mydevice/messages/devicebound?api-version=2016-02-03`). It is expected. It means [the server has fulfilled the request, but there is no new information to send back.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384325(v=vs.85).aspx)

Second, you want to receive the Device-To-Cloud message you have sent. It is unreachable. Because this GET api is used to receive Cloud-To-Device messages.

In short, Device-To-Cloud and Cloud-To-Device are different messaging primitives that Azure IoT hub provides to communicate with a device. And Device-To-Device communication that you want is not supported natively with Azure IoT Hub.

Finally, how to send Cloud-To-Device message?

For test purpose, you can [send Cloud-To-Device message from Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#send). More detailed information you can reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d).

Comment: i am trying to create rest api for Cloud to device messaging by following the steps mentioned in this post  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d  ,it is working fine with console but when i switch it to web api async task is waiting indefinitely.. please guide..

Comment: How did you do that "switch it to web api async task"? Would you show the code?

Comment: // POST api/values
        public async void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
            var commandMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello."));
            await serviceClient.SendAsync("seamed", commandMessage);

        }

Comment: @TahreemSaeed Your code lines work for me. Which line did you halt at?

Comment: yes it does connectionstring was the problem ,thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send cloud-to-device message
POST : https://[iotHubName].azure-devices.net/devices/[deviceId]/messages/deviceBound?api-version=2020-09-30

Header must include Authorization like :
SharedAccessSignature sr=webchatIOTHub.azure-devices.net&sig=lc7seNnczkq7Xj0IDSdFHshTTHEJUDt4y98e9Eoj%2B18%3D&se=1655587178&skn=iothubowner

For SAS (sharedAccessSignature) you have to run PowerShell CLI :
az iot hub generate-sas-token -n [iotHubName]--du 3600000000

Also, you can view the RestAPI when you use the browser to send message to device
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aHaB.jpg)